# JMeter Maven Plugin - remote test machine cannot be configured

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I keep getting this errors (error code bellow) when I run jmeter tests through jenkins on remote slave machines :

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  P E R F O R M A N C E    T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  
[INFO]  
[info]  
[debug] JMeter is called with the following command line arguments: -n -t C:\Performance_Framework\Project\src\test\jmeter\Example.jmx -l C:\Performance_Framework\Project\target\jmeter\results\Example.jtl -d C:\Performance_Framework\Project\target\jmeter -L DEBUG -j C:\Performance_Framework\CMS\target\jmeter\logs\Example.jmx.log -r -R 10.0.20.100,10.0.20.101 -X -Djava.rmi.server.hostname 10.0.20.200 -Dsun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders true
[info] Executing test: Example.jmx

[info] Creating summariser <summary>
[info] Created the tree successfully using C:\Performance_Framework\Project\src\test\jmeter\Example.jmx
[info] Configuring remote engine: 10.0.20.100
[info] error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
[info]  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jmeter.engine.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl_Stub (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
[info] Failed to configure 10.0.20.100
[info] Configuring remote engine: 10.0.20.101
[info] error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
[info]  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jmeter.engine.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl_Stub (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
[info] Failed to configure 10.0.20.101
[info] Stopping remote engines
[info] Remote engines have been stopped
[info] Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.RuntimeException: Following remote engines could not be configured:[10.0.20.100, 10.0.20.101]
[info] Completed Test: Example.jmx
```

Now my current POM settings for the machines:

```
<configuration>
 --------------------------------
        <propertiesSystem>
            <java.rmi.server.hostname>10.0.20.200</java.rmi.server.hostname>
        </propertiesSystem>
        <remoteConfig>
            <startServersBeforeTests>true</startServersBeforeTests>
            <serverList>10.0.20.100,10.0.20.101</serverList>
            <stopServersAfterTests>true</stopServersAfterTests>
        </remoteConfig>                             
</configuration>
```

If I run the tests from JMETER GUI everything is ok, remote host start and execute the tests successfully.

I think that everything is set correctly, jmeter-server.bat is started before tests run on each slave.

Also there's something that I don't understand from this sentence on from jmeter maven plugin wiki :

> runremote command being send to JMeter which will start up any remote
>   servers you have defined in your jmeter.properties when your first
>   test starts.

Which jmeter.properties file, of the project ?If yes, then i don't know how that could be defined as always the target folder is cleaned on every test run, that resulting jmeter properties file is derived.

**Later Edit:** I even created the jmeter.properties file and added in src/test/jmeter dir and defined there the remote hosts, but still nothing.

So what do you suggest guys?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved somehow the issue with the connection by editing the jmeter-server file by adding also the java.rmi.server.hostname.

But what I don't like is the test execution time, it's horrible , even with one thread which is supposed to be be finished in less than 1-2 sec but it's still showing that is trying to receive shutdown message.

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  P E R F O R M A N C E    T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  

[INFO]  
[info]  
[debug] JMeter is called with the following command line arguments: -n -t C:\Performance_Framework\CMS\src\test\jmeter\Example.jmx -l C:\Performance_Framework\CMS\target\jmeter\results\Example.jtl -d C:\Performance_Framework\CMS\target\jmeter -L DEBUG -q C:\Performance_Framework\CMS\src\test\jmeter\jmeter.properties -j C:\Performance_Framework\CMS\target\jmeter\logs\Example.jmx.log -r -X -Djava.rmi.server.hostname 10.0.20.200 -Dsun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders true
[info] Executing test: SearchForModule.jmx

[info] Creating summariser <summary>
[info] Created the tree successfully using C:\Performance_Framework\CMS\src\test\jmeter\SearchForModule.jmx
[info] Configuring remote engine: 10.0.20.100
[info] Configuring remote engine: 10.0.20.101
[info] Starting remote engines
[info] Starting the test @ Thu Jul 30 13:48:23 BST 2015 (1438260503717)

[info] Remote engines have been started
[info] Waiting for possible shutdown message on port 4445
```

Is something that is wrong on jenkins side, tomcat webapp?

Comment: I am getting the exact same error `no security manager: RMI class loader disabled`.  I've exhausted the internet.  Do you know what you did exactly to solve it?

Comment: As I mentioned above I resolved the issue by defining the hostname in jmeter-server.bat 

But I think that first you need to check if ports are not filtred by a firewall on the other side of the slaves.

Therefore follow the instructions from this link [link]http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html

Comment: And define another rmi registry port and server port that you know is open.